# Default Html5 Video Poster

Tags: html5-video

I have more than 300 video posts, and they all have different <video poster="video-poster.jpg">. but now I'm thinking of replacing all the video posters that have been published with just one picture. is it possible?

Comment: yes... as the poster is just a jpg, you can have each video element point to the same file (or am I missing your question)...?

Comment: I mean, can I overwrite my old video poster to the new poster without edit all my blog posts

Comment: depends on blogging platform. you might be able to write a script, or use (eg) .httaccess to redirect requests for the 'old' image to the 'new' and then you don't have to edit the posts (unless you use the images elsewhere)